# Exception thrown while creating a jdbc driver in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I've created the "model" app which works with database(Spring+Hibernate), it works fine when I launch it for testing with main() method:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext =
            new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/ApplicationContext.xml");
    CityService service =
            (CityService) applicationContext.getBean("cityService");
    //all other methods
```

But when I build that app into the .jar file and include it in my Spring MVC webapp as dependency and trying to use CityService inside a controller, it throws an exception:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/delivery'
...
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

When building "model" app into .jar I commented testing beans:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

<context:spring-configured />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.userok.pet.delivery.model">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
                            type="regex" />
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
                            type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!--beans used for testing-->
<!--<bean class="com.userok.pet.delivery.model.service.CargoService"
        id="packageService"/>
<bean class="com.userok.pet.delivery.model.dao.CargoDAO"
        id="packageDao"/>
<bean class="com.userok.pet.delivery.model.service.CityService"
        id="cityService"/>
<bean class="com.userok.pet.delivery.model.dao.CityDAO"
        id="cityDao"/>
-->

<tx:annotation-driven
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

I wonder why this happens since model app worked properly.

Comment: The problem could be in your hard-coded path to application context. E.g. in spring boot we placed application.properties file in resources folder and annotated our configuration with @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") You probably could try to put your ApplicationContext.xml in resources folder (no subfolder) and try ApplicationContext applicationContext =
            new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have this property defined somewhere "database.driverClassName".  Make sure it's set to "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".

Or just edit the bean org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource and change the property "driverClassName" to "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".  Not elegant, but it should get you started.